# How to delete data from the no of tables, without increasing the transaction logfile

Tags: sql-server, file, logging, transactions

We are trying to delete the data from tables which have not been used since many years.
If we are doing CRUD operations on tables SQL Server log file size is going to be increased,

and our goal is that not to increase size the log file, or any system resources,

Is there any other solutions?

Comment: You can't. Even `TRUNCATE` will increase the size of the log file for a period of time. Any operation in SQL Server will consume resources, and minimally while that operation is incomplete details of it will be stored in the log file so that in the event of a failure it can be rolled back. That is by design and very much wanted behaviour. This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info)

Comment: Larnu, i implemented TRANSACTION Explicitly, apart from SQL Server Default behavior, either all will be committed or all will be Rollbacked. but in the Positive case Even though no errors and Data going to be committed we should restrict the Growth of the  LOG File, Please suggest..

Comment: My comment is unchanged. Explicit transaction or not changes nothing about my initial statement.

Comment: If you delete, or update, any rows in a table SQL Server *will* log the operation - if it didn't, and something failed during the operation, it would not be able to roll the data back and meet the core *acid* properties of a transaction. You might consider instead inserting the rows to keep in a new table and then dropping the original? You will, of course *use resources*.

Comment: Like Larnu commented, this seems a lot like XY problem. You should really explain what are you actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Because any data movment into table in a RDBMS is a transaction, all the data will be logged. If you want to not have transaction, the only way is to return to the old ages of CoBOL and ISAM files...

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue and used the below code to delete 10,000 records at a time, until the table is empty.

```
DECLARE @Rowcount INT = 1
WHILE @Rowcount > 0
BEGIN
DELETE TOP (10000) 
  FROM TABLE
  SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```